# ¿Cuanto tiempo tiene el OP al crear una pregunta en Ingles y traducirla para que no sea cerrada?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Lo formulo porque he visto muchas preguntas formuladas en Ingles que son de hace meses, por la pregunta:

¿Hay algun plazo exacto para que el OP edite la pregunta y no sea cerrada?

**Ejemplos**

- [Chart.js How group same values in xAxes?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411987/chart-js-how-group-same-values-in-xaxes)
- [How to show 98th percentile in jmeter test results dashboard](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379373/how-to-show-98th-percentile-in-jmeter-test-results-dashboard)
- [¿How to read line by line of every file using Wholetextfiles to replace data?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411728/how-to-read-line-by-line-of-every-file-using-wholetextfiles-to-replace-data)

O simplemente se tiene que ir a cada pregunta en Ingles y reportarla para cerrarla

PSD: Si entra en el tema, tambien aplicaria para las preguntas mal formuladas pasadas

Comment: No es cuestión de si hay que esperar o no: si ves una publicación que está en la forma X, actúa como si siempre haya estado así. Vota para cerrar, para reabrir, edita, comenta... como si fuera su situación final. Si luego se edita, pues cambias el voto. Para esto va muy bien la funcíon de "seguir".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay un tiempo... dependiendo cuando se hacen, es que tan rapido se cierran...

Si, hay que cerrar todas las que esten en ingles... dar una oportunidad de editarlas, y si no cerrarlas...

Con lo de las preguntas mal formuladas, tampoco hay tiempo... No exiten tiempos para hacer o dejar de hacer algo. Solo se toma caso por caso.

Comment: debes decirle que se cierran para evitar votos negativos y comentarios o respuestas no adecuadas, y que el OP tiene la opción de editar la respuesta cerrada y solicitar la re-apertura.

Comment: el tiempoo para todo esto depende de las sircunstancias.

Comment: Aun no me queda claro, si no existen tiempos para hacer eso y se toma caso por caso, entonces que va a suceder "ahora" con esas preguntas de ejemplo que puse?

Comment: Las preguntas se acaban cerrando cuando la gente que tiene permisos para ver las colas de reportes van avanzando con todos los reportes que hay y se llega a una cantidad X de votos para cerrarla. Imagino que los moderadores diamantados como el señor gbianchi por ejemplo pueden cerrarlas personalmente, pero en general, creo que la mayoría dependen del esfuerzo de la comunidad entera, que es como se modera todo SO basicamente :)

Comment: @JuanRivera ya estan cerradas... no se hace nada mas.. se cierran...

Comment: @Benito-B entiendo, esa era la respuesta que veo: No hay tiempo porque la comunidad y los moderadores estan viendo este tipo de preguntas por lo cual llevara su "tiempo" en solucionarse

Comment: @JuanRivera no. No hay tiempos, porque no hay tiempos definidos... El tiempo que le lleve a la comunidad (o a los moderadores diamantados) no esta definido... es cuando se puede.. a veces es rapidisimo, a veces tardamos mas...

Comment: te falto explicar que existe una cola para estas reviciones... y que el resultado es lo que se aplica... ya que no todos tienen acceso a esa cola es importante mensionarlo para que no crean que lo hace un bot XD